# Multiple curves with different colors

Tags: r, matrix, curve

I got some problems... I'm pretty new in R and I guess this question may appear easy for some of you, but I have no clue how to solve it.

1. I got a Table like Below and i want draw some curves. I want the curve to have different colors and the label of x to be like x = "10^-x".
2. I want after this to draw a line in y = 0.5 and y = 0.9 so i can see how many elements I got in 50% and 90%.

Can anybody help me out of this?

**P.S: Here is the Table: xy is a matrix as u can see, the x-values repeat themselves, so every time it starts over it's a new curve to draw.**

```
       x          y
 [1,] -10 1.14259527
 [2,]  -9 1.15024188
 [3,]  -8 1.10517450
 [4,]  -7 1.00961311
 [5,]  -6 0.71238360
 [6,]  -5 0.20355333
 [7,]  -4 0.04061895
 [8,] -10 1.11022461
 [9,]  -9 1.11083317
[10,]  -8 1.07867942
[11,]  -7 0.98422000
[12,]  -6 0.73539660
[13,]  -5 0.36134577
[14,]  -4 0.18124645
[15,] -10 2.13212408
[16,]  -9 1.14529425
[17,]  -8 1.25102307
[18,]  -7 1.16045169
[19,]  -6 0.50321380
[20,]  -5 0.15422609
[21,]  -4 0.10198811
```

Comment: I recommend you add the tag R

Answer (score 1):

This may get you started. I assume your matrix is called `xy`.

```
my.data <- data.frame(xy)

library(ggplot2) # you may have to install the package
```

Create some labels:

```
my_labels <- parse(text = paste("x^", seq(-10, -4, 1), sep = ""))
```

Then plot ...

```
ggplot(my.data) +
   geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(x))) +
   geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(x))) +
   scale_x_continuous("x", breaks = seq(-10, -4, 1), labels = my_labels)
```

Comment: Hey... The answer isn't complete... I'm still missing the part i get change the X-axis to not display "-10, -9, ..., -4", but "1E-10, 1E-9, ..., 1E-4". How can i change the label of this X-axis in this code? Thanks

Comment: I edited the original response to include the labels. You actually manipulate or change the labels of the X-axis with the `scale_x_continuous()` line. This legend addition should also work with the example mpalanco provided.

Comment: It's great, that's exactly what i was looking for... It works just perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more question? Can i display the result in scientific way like 1e-10 for example instead of 10^-10... By just writing 1e in place of "x" i get an error: Error in parse(text = paste("1e^", seq(-10, -4, 1), sep = "")) : 
  <text>:1:1: unexpected input
1: 1e^

Comment: You should be able to supply any character vector as labels so long as the number of elements in my_labels matches the number of tick marks in the plot. This should work:

`my_labels <- paste("1E", seq(-10, -4, 1), sep = "")`

Comment: And this should also work: `my_labels <- parse(text = 10^(-10:-4))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an additional column to mark the beginning of the new curves (A, B and C in the example) and then the following code

```
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=z, colour=z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

data:

```
 df <- structure(list(x = c(-10L, -9L, -8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -10L, 
-9L, -8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -10L, -9L, -8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, 
-4L), y = c(1.14259527, 1.15024188, 1.1051745, 1.00961311, 0.7123836, 
0.20355333, 0.04061895, 1.11022461, 1.11083317, 1.07867942, 0.98422, 
0.7353966, 0.36134577, 0.18124645, 2.13212408, 1.14529425, 1.25102307, 
1.16045169, 0.5032138, 0.15422609, 0.10198811), z = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Output:

```
     x          y z
1  -10 1.14259527 A
2   -9 1.15024188 A
3   -8 1.10517450 A
4   -7 1.00961311 A
5   -6 0.71238360 A
6   -5 0.20355333 A
7   -4 0.04061895 A
8  -10 1.11022461 B
9   -9 1.11083317 B
10  -8 1.07867942 B
11  -7 0.98422000 B
12  -6 0.73539660 B
13  -5 0.36134577 B
14  -4 0.18124645 B
15 -10 2.13212408 C
16  -9 1.14529425 C
17  -8 1.25102307 C
18  -7 1.16045169 C
19  -6 0.50321380 C
20  -5 0.15422609 C
21  -4 0.10198811 C
```